# Can you verify that the sender of an event hasn't been faked?

Tags: pusher

Let's say I have a chat room and everyone is subscribed to the channel: `private-chatroom`

Anyone can send an event `client-message` with data like:

```
{
  sender_user_id: 1,
  text: "Hello everyone!"
}
```

Other users would receive that event and display the message along with the `sender_user_id` it received (taking it at face value).

How could you verify it was really sent by `user #1` without having to involve my server everytime someone sends a message.

*P.S. I'm using auth which allows only logged in users to send messages, but no further verification is done to verify faked user ids afterwards*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scenario, you cannot. Even adding an authentication signature would do little, because I could fake being some user that has not yet logged in (if e.g. the user ID's are predictable). Then again, I would need to consider things like replay attacks, so I'd need to also include a timestamp in the authentication process.

To be able to trust the system I'd need an extra service that maps a sender id with its public key. Then whenever I receive a message from user X and I don't have his public key, I can ask the trusted server by sending id=X and getting a public key with an expiry date (I can cache that afterwards), and use it to authenticate the message body and timestamp, and verify that the timestamp is greater than the last received timestamp from X:

```
1234567: X: hash=0xdeadbeef: "Debit me USD 50,74"
1234511: Y: hash=0xdeafd00d: "OK, thanks"
1234567: X: hash=0xdeadbeef: "Debit me USD 50,74"
1234515: Y: hash=0xbaadf00d: "Wait, what?"
```

(Here X and Y's clocks are deliberately not synced - the important thing is that they're both monotonically increasing).

So you need to either modify the server behaviour or *add a secondary, trusted authentication server*, as well as modifying the client protocol (timestamp, hash) and behaviour (key verification, signing...). The connection between the two servers is not trivial: the key server must access the authentication data from the primary server and *trust* whoever connects to it.

It seems to me that the simplest way to go is that **the chat server overwrites the sender ID based on the user authentication**. This should be trivial to do and actually I'd expect things to work this way from the start.

Note that the work necessary on the chat server so that the authentication server can supply reliable information is not negligible - i.e., the secondary server is not a "zero intervention on the chat server" at all. Actually it is more complicated than just injecting the authenticated user ID in the messages on the chat server's part. The main difference is that now you're only interacting with the authentication module, and in some scenarios this *might* be easier to do:

> How could you verify it was really sent by user #1 without having to involve **my** server **every time** someone sends a message.

When the user first creates the account on the main chat server (so only *once* in that user's lifetime), the chat server connects with the key server on a trusted connection and asks for a key pair for user 12345. The key server creates the pair and sends the private key to the chat server, who supplies it to the user. The chat server needs do nothing further. The client can now add timestamp and signed hash to each message. Whoever wants to verify the message only needs to interact with the key server, and only once for each sender.

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaboration - very helpful notes!!